# ERROR Warning: mkdir(): File exists in

Tags: php, mkdir

Hola quiero hacer una pregunta, estoy creando un nuevo usuario con foto de perfil y al crear y subir la imagen tengo problemas.

> Warning: mkdir(): File exists in C:\wamp64\www\gsrb\controladores\usuarios.controlador.php on line 275

En la línea 275

```
mkdir(utf8_decode($directorio), 0700);
```

Parte del código de mi controlador

```
                /*=============================================

                 VALIDAR IMAGEN

                 =============================================*/

                 $ruta = "";

                 if (isset($_FILES['nuevaFoto']["tmp_name"])) {

                        list($ancho, $alto) = getimagesize($_FILES["nuevaFoto"]["tmp_name"]); //saber las propiedades

                        $nuevoAncho = 500;

                        $nuevoAlto = 500;

                        /*=============================================

                        CREAMOS EL DIRECTORIO DONDE VAMOS A GUARDAR LA FOTO DEL USUARIO

                        =============================================*/

                        $directorio = "vistas/img/usuarios/".$_POST["nuevoNombre"];

                        mkdir(utf8_decode($directorio), 0700);

                        /*=============================================

                        DE ACUERDO AL TIPO DE IMAGEN APLICAMOS LAS FUNCIONES POR DEFECTO DE PHP

                        =============================================*/

                        if($_FILES["nuevaFoto"]["type"] == "image/jpeg"){

                                /*=============================================

                                GUARDAMOS LA IMAGEN EN EL DIRECTORIO

                                =============================================*/

                                $aleatorio = mt_rand(100,999);

                                $ruta = "vistas/img/usuarios/".$_POST["nuevoNombre"]."/".$aleatorio.".jpg";

                                $origen = imagecreatefromjpeg($_FILES["nuevaFoto"]["tmp_name"]);

                                $destino = imagecreatetruecolor($nuevoAncho, $nuevoAlto);

                                imagecopyresized($destino, $origen, 0, 0, 0, 0, $nuevoAncho, $nuevoAlto, $ancho, $alto);

                                imagejpeg($destino, utf8_decode($ruta));

                            }
```

Comment: Debes verificar si existe la carpeta antes de intentar crearla, sino te aparece ese error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para verificar si la carpeta existe antes de crearla puedes hacerlo así, usando la función [is_dir()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.is-dir.php):

```
if (!is_dir(utf8_decode($directorio))) {
    if (!mkdir(utf8_decode($directorio), 0700)) {
        die("Error durante la creación de la carpeta ".utf8_decode($directorio).". Revisa la ruta y los permisos que tengas";
    }
}
```

Comment: Disculpa donde reviso la ruta y los permisos

Comment: En tu sistema de archivos donde esté corriendo tu web, claro.  Si tienes acceso a un terminal en ese sistema de archivos vete a la ruta a pelo y a ver si te deja con tu usuario o quizas es que debes indicarle una ruta más completa y precisa.  Si te deja llegar intenta crear la carpeta también desde el terminal a ver si te deja, y así podrás descubrir el error que te da el sistema tambien cuando lo haces.

Comment: Normalmente cuando se intenta crear una carpeta se pone la ruta de forma absoluta, no relativa como tu has hecho aquí:  `$directorio = "vistas/img/usuarios/".$_POST["nuevoNombre"];`... más bien seria algo asi como `$directorio = "/home/cuenta/public_html/vistas/img/usuarios/".$_POST["nuevoNombre"];`

Comment: Por tu error creo que la ruta que debes poner podría ser esta: `$directorio = "/wamp64/www/gsrb/vistas/img/usuarios/".$_POST["nuevoNombre"];` (no uso windows y no se como deben ponerse los path en ese caso, si con la `C://` o sin, lo siento)

Comment: Muchas gracias he podido entender el error

Comment: me alegro... esta pensando que en lugar de poner la ruta completa **actual**, deberias usar `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` para hallar la ruta de la raiz de tu web, y a partir de alli agregar la ruta hacia las imágenes de usuario que falte.  De este modo podrás copiar tu proyecto en cualquier otro lugar sin tener que preocuparte demasiado de la ruta que habias dejado hardcodeada anteriormente.  Si haces un `echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];` lo entenderás.